# jquery click everything but open div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I write a jquery action so that when anything on a web page is clicked EXCEPT a certain div, then the query performs a function?

Comment: Use not() http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my way:

```
$(document).on("click", function(){
    alert('foo');
});
$('#yourdiv').on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v3N2T/5/

The idea is that you put the click event on the whole page and then catch the click on the element you don't want to do the action and prevent it from propogating the click event up to the document click event.

It might interact badly if you have any other click event stuff going on but you may have that problem anyway...

P.S. Credit to Adrian for his original answer that allowed me to develop this solution much more quickly by just modifying his. :)

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.7, the use of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is encouraged:

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(#yourdiv)", function(){
    //do your thing

    //important: return false to avoid repeating the call for each DOM element in
    //the hierarchy
    return false;
})
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/v3N2T/8/

Now, there's a caveat: in the fiddle example, it will appear that the not wanted div is being clicked. But, in fact, the click event is being fired by its parent.

Comment: This doesn't work either. http://jsfiddle.net/v3N2T/ It will execute the function for every element up the dom chain it looks like. ie I click on the parent div of the not one and get four alerts, I click on the not div and get teh same four alerts. Presumably if I put in a sibling and clicked on that I'd get five because it is just the div itself that is not doing what you want...

Comment: Good good. Saves me from having to go and finish my solution when I should be doing real work. ;-)

Comment: @Chris fixed the propagation issue

Comment: @Adrian: this still has the problem that when you click on the "not" div the click handler on its parent gets thrown so you still get an action taken as the fiddle Rocket Hazmat linked shows. I think it might require you to do something such as my answer which is to explicitly catch the click on the element you want to exclude and explicitly tell it to do nothing.

Comment: @Chris Duly noted. Just upvoted your answer, which is the most suitable. I'll leave my around because there was some research done with results that someone might be interested

Comment: @Adrian: that and I flagrantly stole your original answer to create mine. :) I was hoping that there was a more elegant way to do this I have to admit. What I did feels a bit hacky but I can't think of any other options since what you've tried doesn't work. :(